# Using QTimeEdit with time_t - Adapter pattern C++

Tags: c++, qt, design-patterns, adapter, qtimeedit

I need to make an adapter for **QTimeEdit** to use it with **time_t** in:

1. constructor QTimeEdit(time_t)
2. void setTime(time_t)
3. time_t time()
   I did 1. and its working.

```
class QTimeEditAdapter: public QTimeEdit {
public:
    QTimeEditAdapter(time_t t) {
        tm1 = t;
        tm *ltm = localtime(&tm1);
        int hours = ltm->tm_hour;
        int min = ltm->tm_min;
        this->setTime(QTime(hours,min));
    }
private:
    time_t tm1;
};
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    time_t tm1;
    tm1 = time(NULL);

    //other qt widgets code

    QTimeEdit* timeEdit = new QTimeEditAdapter(tm1);

    //more other qt widgets code
```

But if I'm adapting setTime by adding

```
void setTime(time_t t1)
```

to the class its redefines setTime and I'm getting mistakes from both constructor and method setTime.
I didn't found any other method to set time in QTimeEdit but I guess there must be a way better than my

Comment: I would suggest /composition over inheritance/ and not inherit from QTimeEdit (you're not reimplementing a virtual function, so why inheritance) but simply use a free convenience function to convert from time_t to QTime and pass that to QTimeEdit. (Note that you could also create a QDateTime from time_t and call time() on it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A derived-class member with the same name as a member of the base
>   class hides direct use off the base-class member -- C++ Primer (5th Edition), Pg 618

Function overloading based on the parameter list is not possible between derived and base classes. If you make a call like `this->setTime(QTime(hours,min));` where `this` is a `QTimeEditAdapter`, only your new `QTimeEditAdapter::setTime(time_t)` will be considered in the overload resolution. This causes the compile error.

To workaround this, you could directly reference the base-class in the constructor:

```
QTimeEditAdapter::setTime(QTime(hours,min));
```

but this won't help other users of your adaptor access the original `setTime`.

Another workaround would be to instead add the following:

```
void setTime(QTime qt)
{
        QTimeEdit::setTime(qt);
}
```

This fixes the issue, but now you are responsible for enumerating all (present or future) possible overloads that the base class defines.

To avoid these tricky issues it's probably better to just pick a different method name for your `QTimeEditAdapter::setTime(time_t)` method.